# creating dynamic index from kafka-filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

software version: ES-OSS-7.4.2， filebeat-OSS-7.4.2

following is my filebeat.yml  and grok pipeline

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: kafka
  hosts:
    - test-bigdata-kafka0003:9092
    - test-bigdata-kafka0002:9092
    - test-bigdata-kafka0001:9092
  topics: ["bigdata-k8s-test-serverlog"]
  group_id: "filebeat-kafka-test"
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  _source.enabled: true
setup.template.name: "test"
setup.template.pattern: "test-*"
setup.template.overwrite: true
setup.template.enabled: true
setup.ilm.enable: true
setup.ilm.rollover_alias: "test"
setup.kibana:
  host: "https://xxx:8080"
  username: "superuser"
  password: "123456"
  ssl.verification_mode: none
output.elasticsearch:
  index: "test-%{[jiserver]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  pipeline: "test-pipeline"
  hosts: ["xxx:8200"]
  username: "superuser"
  password: "123456"
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

pipeline.json

```
{
    "description": "Test pipeline",
    "processors": [
        {
            "grok": {
                "field": "message",
                "patterns": ["%{CUSTOMTIME:timestamp} (?:%{NOTSPACE:jiserver}|-) (?:%{NOTSPACE:hostname}|-) (?:%{LOGLEVEL:level}|-) (?:%{NOTSPACE:thread}|-) (?:%{NOTSPACE:class}|-) (?:%{NOTSPACE:method}|-) (?:%{NOTSPACE:line}|-) (?:%{CUSTOMDATA:message}|-)"],
                "pattern_definitions": {
                    "CUSTOMTIME": "%{YEAR}[- ]%{MONTHNUM}[- ]%{MONTHDAY}[- ]%{TIME}",
                    "CUSTOMDATA": "((%{GREEDYDATA})[[:space:]]?)+"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "on_failure": [
        {
          "set": {
            "field": "error_information",
            "value": "Processor {{ _ingest.on_failure_processor_type }} with tag {{ _ingest.on_failure_processor_tag }} in pipeline {{ _ingest.on_failure_pipeline }} failed with message {{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

I use grok split the message to different field,  one of them is  `jiserver` . And I want my index dynamicly name with jiserver, how to do . above setting is not work, and recevie error

```
[elasticsearch] elasticsearch/client.go:541 Bulk item insert failed (i=0, status=500): {"type":"string_index_out_of_bounds_exception","reason":"String index out of range: 0"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution 。  filebeat.yml add a script processor

```
processors:
  - script:
      lang: javascript
      id: my_filter
      source: >
        function process(event) {
            var message = event.Get("message");
            var name = message.split(" ")
            event.Put("jiserver", name[2])
        }
```